# jquery toggle and transparent PNG

Tags: jquery, png, transparent

I have a jquery toggle that animates and displays a DIV.  I have a transparent PNG, drop shadow type background image, and when it first appears, I see a black background then it disappears once the image loads...

is there a way around that? is that a bug?  I have it animating slow, so maybe that has something to do with it.

should I just make it show()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in IE.

No current version of IE supports the `opacity` CSS proeprty, so jQuery uses the Alpha filter instead.  However, filters force the element to be fully opaque, so they don't work orrectly with transparent PNGs.

To use transparent PNGs in semi-transparent elements, the PNGs need to be applied using the AlphaImageLoader filter (even in IE8).  For example:

```
if ($.browser.msie)
    $(something).css({
        background: 'none',
        filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="/Folder/Image.png", sizingMethod="scale"),alpha(opacity=100)'
    });
```

(This code works; I'm using it right now)

Comment: Note that even then, the combination of `alphaimageloader` and `alpha` isn't quite the same as `opacity` would be. The transparency per pixel seems to be `max(image_opacity, filter_opacity)` instead of `image_opacity*filter_opacity`. (This is not always a displeasing effect in an animation.)

Comment: can i add that to my existing .js file?  when i do, i get an error "missng ");"... here is what i have: 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#business-blue').hide();
$('a#biz-blue-lnk').click(function() {
$('#business-blue').animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 800);
return false; });
});

Comment: @SLaks it looks like there is a missing ' tick mark... becuase i am getting an error...